# Custom Proxies for Touch project in Sencha Architect

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-architect

I am rebuilding a very old existing Sencha Touch app within the newest version of Sencha Architect. The old version was using custom proxies associated with a couple of models to handle authentication of data, and in order for the new version to work properly without massive amounts of reconstruction, it would be convenient to be able to utilise these proxies.

What is the best way (or is there even a way) of using them with the new app in architect? So far I have only been able to use preset ones but these will not do the job.

Comment: why it's not feat for the new architecture?

can you update your post with the old ones so we can see how they build?